# Navigation Drawer icons (made with GIMP) take too much space

Tags: android, layout, navigation, android-widget, navigation-drawer

I am following the Android tutorial that suggests to use V4 [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) that should give me on the left side an hamburger navigation icon.
What happens instead is that if I use one icon I have this result:

[image: icon made with Gimp]

If instead I use another ***similar*** icon it is even worse and occupies all the space:
[image: similar icon different behaviour]

I do not understand:

**1)** How can I use the second icon in a way that is on the left, while the other icons continue to appear, like one would expect from a Navigation Drawer?

**2)** Why two different icons have such a different behaviour, after all I worked them with gimp giving them 200x200 pixels dimensions

**My Main Class:**

```
 import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity{

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new   ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
getActionBar().setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
String[] provaListaDrawer = {"List1", "List2", "List3"};
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout =
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.app_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)

        {

            /**
             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state.
             */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                Log.d("IVO", "onDrawerClosed");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /**
             * Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state.
             */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                Log.d("IVO", "onDrawerOpened");

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        }
        ;

        ListView mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

     mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_view,provaListaDrawer));

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//
    // getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

//     ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
//       actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
//      actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
//      actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
//      View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
//       actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
//     Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
//        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);




    }
    //other methods
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    >
    <!-- The main content view -->

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_as_list"
    android:name="ivano.android.com.xx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="19dp"
        android:background="@drawable/image_background"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You should use [Support Navigation Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). That will help with alignment. [This](http://codetheory.in/android-navigation-drawer/) blog post tells you how to use the default hamburger icon. You can color it whatever color you want with a theme.

Comment: @nukeforum Thank you for your interest; for Support Navigation Bar you give me a link that is the same I indicated in my post, namely I guess you mean to use  the V4 libraries, that is exactly what I am using. What i do not understand is why the icon has a behavior different than expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
basically I download the official material design icon and it works as a charm
https://design.google.com/icons/index.html

> dimensions 48x48; width 48 pixels; height 48 pixels; bit depth 32;

I have chosen the reorder icon.